# How do you find the generators of $E_{10}$?

Tags: lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras

$E_{10}$ is a hyperbolic Lie group, i.e. one that not only has infinite generators, but one where the number of generators grows exponentially when you commutate more elements of the algebra. So at present there is no way to simply represent the generators. ($E_{9}$ is a bit easier since the generators are basically $E_8$ but with an additional parameter which takes numbers in $\mathbb{N}$).

I am finding it hard to find details on how to count the number of generators at each level.

I know it is not easy since you have to work out which generators are linear combinations of others which is non-trivial.

Any ideas how to do this?